# validation failed error parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am getting validation failed error in my parse cloud code.Here "postId" is a pointer to the post class.Here is my code-

```
 Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("likes",function(request,response){
    var posts=Parse.Object.extend("posts");
    var query=new Parse.Query(posts);
    query.include("postAuthor");
    query.equalTo("objectId",request.object.get("postId").get("objectId"));
    query.find({
       success:function(results){
           if(results.length==0){
              response.error();
           }else{response.success();}

       },
       error:function(error){
           response.error(error);
       }
    });
 });
```

Also if I modify the equalTo method like

```
query.equalTo("objectId",request.object.get("postId"));
```

the error goes away but the results array returned in the success callback has a length==0 that means no object gets retrieved even though it exists in the data browser.Not sure if this is a bug or something that I am doing wrong.Please help.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to check if `request.object.get("postId")` exists. When you save any record in your `likes` class, do you always set the `postId` ? If not, then there will be no `postId` in your request object and your code will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.The problem was this line-

```
  query.equalTo("objectId",request.object.get("postId").get("objectId"));
```

and even

```
   query.equalTo("objectId",request.object.get("postId"));
```

failed because I was not specifying any object id for it to compare to and passing a json object in it instead.Changing it to

```
   query.equalTo("objectId",request.object.get("postId").id);
```

solved the problem for me.